# Usage of DownloadToByteArray in Windows.Azure.Storage Version 3.0.2.0

Tags: image, azure, arrays, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have just updated my azure windows storage version to Version 3.0.2.0. I have had to update my code to suit the new version. This has mainly worked but I am having problems updating my code for downloading an image file to a byte array. I am trying:

```
    Dim storageAccount As CloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
        CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"))

    'Create the blob client.
    Dim blobClient As CloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient()

    'Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
    Dim container As CloudBlobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("container")

    'Retrieve reference to a blob named "photo1.jpg".
    Dim blockBlob As CloudBlockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("photo1.jpg")

    Try
        Dim byteData As Byte() = {}
        blockBlob.DownloadToByteArray(byteData, 0)
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(byteData)
    Catch ex As Exception
        CreateErrorLog(ex, "ProcessRequest")

    End Try
```

This fails with the error: "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad request".

I am downloading the image to display it on a webpage. I am doing this by using an IHttpHandler. I have been unable to find any examples of the usage of DownloadToByteArray. Can anyone let me know the correct way to download my blob file.

Comment: Are you targeting the Windows Azure Storage Emulator or an actual account on Windows Azure?

Comment: I'm running the code locally but targeting an account on Windows Azure. I am able to upload the image to azure and I can see the file in the blob storage in my account. But I then get an error when I try to display the image I have just uploaded on my webpage.

Comment: Do you have a Fiddler trace of the request and response? I tried running your code, but did not get a 400 response. The only change I made was to define the byteData as "Dim byteData(1024) As Byte" for a 1K blob.

Comment: I've run it with Fiddler. The only thing that I can see that looks odd is that the content-type of the blob is shown as 'application/xml'. The image in the blob store has a content type of 'image/gif'. I've tried explicitly setting the content-type of blockBlob in the code but it is still showing as content-type of 'application/xml' in the Fiddler trace. Fiddler does show that 539 bytes have been downloaded.

Comment: I've now tried to use DownloadToByteArray in another function. This time I am not getting the 400 bad request error. Instead it times out giving the error 'Memory stream is not expandable'. Any clues as to what is going on? The content-type of the file is shown correctly in Fiddler for this request.

Comment: I've fixed the 'Memory stream is not expandable' error so DownloadToByteArray now works fine in my other function. It is still giving the 400 error in the original routine. The only difference is that the troublesome routine is running within an IHttpHandler.

Comment: I even tried the code in an IHttpHandler, but could not repro the issue. Please compare the successful and the failing requests in Fiddler and check the header differences.

Comment: I'm having similar problems, mate. I *think* we need a new SDK or something ?? It's very frustrating - i can't get any code to work with the new 3.+ packages.

Comment: @Serdar Thanks for your help. I have just come back to this problem and got it sorted. I had used the wrong container name. When debugging I made the mistake of thinking that because the code didn't fail on the line Dim blockBlob As CloudBlockBlob that it had correctly found the blob when in fact it can't have done because the container name was incorrect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've rechecked this and found that I was using the wrong container name. So the code is correct. I had assumed that the correct blob had been found because the code didn't fail on the line:

```
Dim blockBlob As CloudBlockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("photo1.jpg")
```

but it can't have been because the container name was incorrect!